# Program for mixing multiple inputs and outputting to single stream

Tags: software, recommendations, mixer, multichannel

Is there some software that I can use that cane take multiple audio inputs, say from a mic, and two virtual audio cables, mix them so I can change volumes and gain and all that, and then output to another source to then use somewhere else?

I'm specifically asking because I am starting to stream on twitch.tv, and I would love the ability to do this without a separate mixing board outside the computer, which even gets more complicated to output, mix and then input back into the same PC.

Ideally I am looking for some software that even just allows me to take in as many sources as I want, and change their volumes on the fly as I am outputting live to my twitch.tv stream.

I'm on Windows.

Comment: For OSX, there's [Soundflower](https://github.com/RogueAmoeba/Soundflower), which may be able to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: http://www.jackaudio.org/faq/ might also be an option for other OS.

Comment: I will check out jack, thanks @audionuma, I forgot to mention that I'm on Windows, I edited the original question to include that.

Comment: [VoiceMeeter](https://vb-audio.com/Voicemeeter/potato.htm) This does the trick